# Drupal commerce line items + images

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy, commerce

I have a drupal commerce + line items + taxonomies + fancy attributes.

```
Product:    
-sku    
-...    
-shape (product line item) - taxonomies (text + image)
```

[image]

And taxonomies images doesn’t display at all (text is ok).

When I do it with product variations (shape (product field) - taxonomies (image)) everything is ok, but I need 3 options of variation with many many attributes and it’s not possible to create million of SKU products for the same item.

How I’ll display the taxonomy image from a line item?
(maybe some other solution?)